# How to click a button in selenium webdriver using java?

Tags: selenium

```
<div class="mscrm-globalqc-actionsdiv">
<button id="globalquickcreate_save_button_NavBarGloablQuickCreate" class="mscrm-globalqc-actionbutton" button_quickiframe_id="NavBarGloablQuickCreate">Save</button>
```

I need to click on the above mentioned Save button. Am using Selenium Webdriver and writing it in java language.

Comment: And, what have you tried with?

Comment: You don't want to use id?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("globalquickcreate_save_button_NavBarGloablQuickCreate")).click();

Comment: I tried by id but it says element not found.

Comment: Obviously you need to give more code for a proper answer.  All the answers below are correct with your code snippet.  There is something else going on, as stated it could be in a frame or something.

Comment: and I just realized this is a necropost.

Answer (score 2):

Give xpath a try. Possible reason could the duplicate id. I would try with the xpath text based search

```
By byXpath = By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Save')]");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byXpath ));
myDynamicElement.click();
```

Comment: @rjt Please try with the explicit wait as shown above

Comment: Probably failing somewhere else then

Comment: Could you look at the <button> tag again and let me know if there's a case to switch to some frame or anything of that sorts? Cus it's pointing to that only here.

Comment: Could be a possibility. The only thing is that can be inside and iframe and if that's the case you need to switchTo the the iframe

Answer (score 1):

Its simple, all you need to do is first find the reference to the element that you want to click.

In your case you can use id attribute of element button i.e id="globalquickcreate_save_button_NavBarGloablQuickCreate"

So the code would look like this.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("globalquickcreate_save_button_NavBarGloablQuickCreate")).click();
```

~rOhit

Answer (score 1):

code would look like this: Sometimes click() function doesn't work so try using sendKeys()function

driver.findElement(By.id("globalquickcreate_save_button_NavBarGloablQuickCreate")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until, save button visible. After that only, you have to click save button.

**Steps**

1.Create Firefox browser session

2.Navigate to the page and do some operation [ Whatever you wants as per your requirements]

3.Wait until, save button visible

4.Then click save button.

```
public void buttonClick()
{
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
waitForElementInDOM(driver, "globalquickcreate_save_button_NavBarGloablQuickCreate", 15);
WebElement saveButtonElement = driver.findElement(By.id("globalquickcreate_save_button_NavBarGloablQuickCreate"));

if(saveButtonElement.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Save"))
{
    saveButtonElement.click();  
    System.out.println("Save button clicked ! ! !");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Element not present");
}
}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public void waitForElementInDOM(WebDriver driver,String elementIdentifier, long 
timeOutInSeconds) 
{       
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds );
    try
    {
        //this will wait for element to be visible for 15 seconds
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(elementIdentifier))); 
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e)
    {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```